# $_POST key name length?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am experiencing a very odd behaviour. Say I have the following two `<input type='image'>` (with the `src` attribute equal to the `name` attribute):

```
<input type='image' name='http://farm1.static.flickr.com/224/471627793_fbda6cecbe_s.jpg'>
<input type='image' name='http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4053/4501238330_c5a85162ef_s.jpg'>
```

My question is: why does the first input submit and the second one doesn't? I am using CakePHP and if I click on the second image, the `$this->params['form']` is empty. But when I click on the first image, everything works fine: the `$this->params['form']` contains the correct image name together with it's coordinates from where it was clicked.

This is a very odd behaviour and I believe that this can only happen if `$_POST` limit its keys' length.

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have Suhosin patch installed?

Comment: Have you tried the some other combinations of the fields. For example: 1: Just use one <input> field with the second key. 2: Remove the second input field and gradually increase the length of name.

Comment: POST data is sent in the request body as key=value pairs. As such, there is no inherent limit to either key or value length.

Comment: @N.B.: No, I don't have that patch installed. @Scobal: I tested, and if the key length is higher than 62 characters, it does not submit. But why this strange behaviour?

Comment: @N.B.: Sorry, just found out that I have that patch installed. How can I overwrite the default settings providing that I'm on a paid hosting?

Comment: Sidenote!  Why are you putting a URL in a 'name' attribute?

Comment: Exactly what @Ethan said.  Why are you having an url as the *name* of your input field?

Comment: Because I need to select a Flickr picture and then send its URL to the controller. It was the first solution which has gone into my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP itself does not limit field name length for `multipart/` or `-urlencoded` POST requests.

But suhosin does indeed have http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_name_length with a default of `64`. And your second url is indeed 64 characters long.

Less likely, but also possible is a mod_security setup. It would however spill an error message rather than truncating.

Comment: How do I know whether suhosin is installed? Also where should I look for the mod_security setup? I tested with another randomly generated string and it does the same thing. If the name is over 62 chars (64 with the added _x and _y), the button doesn't submit.

Comment: Ok, I just found out that I have the Suhosin patch. Is there some way to overwrite the defaults? Note that I'm on a paid hosting.

Comment: Well if you pay for your hosting you are entitled to contact the admistrator and ask for a system-side change. Normal settings can be overriden via `php_value` in `.htaccess`. But suhosin seems limited to read them from the central `php.ini` only. If your hoster has it installed, chances are they are running suexec and you have a custom per-account php.ini which they can change for you.

Comment: You have a good point, but as a temporary workaround I've built a custom name attribute, with only the parameter from the Flickr URL which I really need (id, server, farm and secret). But as soon as I will have the necessary time, I will talk to my administrator.

Comment: Don't tell me. I constantly implement workarounds for mod_security, because my hoster takes a day before deploying config fixes.

Comment: If you want to change suhosin values in php.ini - just add them to this file, don't loo

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it's related to the length, according to w3.org:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

so perhaps the problem is related to illegal characters in the name.

Have you tried it in different browsers?

Comment: Haven't. So could the URL pattern of the name attribute be the fault? It is odd, because if there are less than 62 characters, the button submits, no matter it contains a URL.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking the value attribute is submitted for image buttons? This would be a far better idea than using "name" to pass data, assuming it works.

Comment: No, the name attribute is submitted, together with the coords of the place where the user has clicked the button.

Comment: @link ah, quite right. I had tried to read the input[type=image] spec, which is not so very clear on the behaviour.